# Why when using a break point the script will continue and will work fine but without a break point it will not?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Playables;

public class SpaceshipCutscene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Transform[] npcs;
    public Transform console;
    public Camera FPSCamera;
    public Camera mainCamera;
    public Animator[] anim;
    public float rotationSpeed = 3f;
    public float distanceFromConsole;


    private bool moveNpc = false;
    private float sp = 0f;
    private float distance;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, npcs[0].transform.position);
        if (moveNpc)
        {
            // Soldier 2 rotating and looking at player
            Vector3 dir = player.position - npcs[0].position;
            dir.y = 0; // keep the direction strictly horizontal
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
            // slerp to the desired rotation over time
            npcs[0].rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(npcs[0].rotation, rot, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            var dist = Vector3.Distance(npcs[1].position, console.position);
            if (dist < distanceFromConsole)
            {
                sp += Time.deltaTime;
                sp = Mathf.Clamp(sp, 0f, 1f);
                anim[1].SetFloat("WalkingSpeed", sp);
            }

            Vector3 dirToComputer = console.transform.position - npcs[1].position;
            dirToComputer.y = 0;
            Quaternion rot1 = Quaternion.LookRotation(dirToComputer);
            npcs[1].rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(npcs[1].rotation, rot1, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (HoriDoorManager.doorLockState == false && distance < 5f)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.tag == "SpaceshipCutscene")
            {
                FPSCamera.enabled = false;
                mainCamera.enabled = true;
                moveNpc = true;
                anim[0].SetBool("Aiming", true);
                anim[1].SetBool("Walktouse", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calculating the distance between the player and the first npcs since I want the OnTriggerExit to trigger and work on specific direction.

When using a break point on the line:

```
FPSCamera.enabled = false;
```

It stop on this line and then I hit continue and it's getting inside the rest of the code in the Update.

But if I'm not adding a break point on that line it's not working it does nothing. Not giving errors or exception just not getting to the rest of the code in the Update.

Comment: How did you put the break point? A screenshot with steps you followed?

Comment: I found the problem. If I move the character the player too fast it will not calculate the distance good enough but once I'm moving the player very slow it's working. I'm guessing that the problem is with the distance since before using the distance at all it was working fine.

Comment: Try to move your code to `LateUpdate`. It is called after all `Update` calls finished. I guess when you are moving some other `Update` method of the `npcs` might change some values you are trying to rely on. Things that should happen **after** user input should be placed in `LateUpdate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html
OnTriggerExit occurs on the FixedUpdate after the Colliders have stopped touching

Update happens every frame, while FixedUpdate happens on a timer. So things here is probably just out of sync. Creating a break point will ensure that the frame stops and everything is probably aligned when you do that.